# Swift2カスタムキーボードで、キーボード上部に変換候補を出したいが、何を使えばいいのか？

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

1行に候補を複数表示して、それを横スクロールしたい。

(^^) (^^; (^^ ・・・　のような感じで。

ボタンやラベルくらいしか思い浮かばないが、候補文字の横幅は可変ですし、その調整の仕方もわからないです。

なかなかうまくいきません。
https://sites.google.com/a/gclue.jp/swift-docs/ni-yinki100-ios/uikit/uicollectionviewnocellwokasutamaizusuru
あたりが、ヒントかなとも思いますが、キーボード上ではうまく動きません。

最近ではSwiftしか経験ないため（それも始めたばかり）、Objectiv-Cの解析もうまくいきません。
http://objectivec2swift.net/#/converter こんなサイトも使ってみましたが・・・

どうすれば実現可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UICollectionViewを横向きに使うのが簡単だと思いますね。

手前味噌で、かつObjective-Cのコードですが、こちらは参考になるのではないかと存じます。

https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/JapaneseKeyboardKit

Comment: プログラム経験が、 VB6,JAVA,HTML4,Parl,PHPなどでCは経験ないためしっくはっくしています。
やっと少し解読ができてきました。KeyboardCandidateBarやKeyboardCandidateBarCellのあたりでしょうか？
これからSwiftに変換して行ってみます。

Comment: [https://sites.google.com/a/gclue.jp/swift-docs/ni-yinki100-ios/uikit/uicollectionviewnocellwokasutamaizusuru]ここなんかも、参考になりそうですが、セルのサイズが自動可変でないので、そこが使えませんね。ん〜・・・

Comment: どうしても、セルの横幅が、文字数によって自動可変する仕組みが読み解けません・・・

Comment: 鍵はCGRectGetWidthかな？

Comment: たとえば私のコードですと、文字数に合わせてセルの幅を変えているのは https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/JapaneseKeyboardKit/blob/master/JPKB/KeyboardCandidateBar.m#L191-L196 ← この部分のコードですね。